# How to navigate to the tableView when the rightBarButtonItem is pressed?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, pushviewcontroller

I am new for iPhone apps development. In my code, After i select the images and press the done  rightBarButtonItem, i want to navigate to the tableview where i am displaying all the zip files of the selected images. The selection of images with done button and the tableView, both are in different viewControllers. Please tell me as how to navigate to the tableView when i press the done button by modifying my code.

This is how my code looks for done bar button:

```
- (void)updateRightBarButtonItem
{
if (self.allowsMultipleSelection) {
    // Set done button
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
    doneButton.enabled = NO;

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:NO];
    self.doneButton = doneButton;
}
```

And this is how my tableView code looks:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
return [filePathsArray count];
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Main Cell"];
if(cell== nil)
{
    cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"Main Cell"];
}
cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
for(int i=0;i<[filePathsArray count];i++)
{
    if(indexPath.row==i)
        cell.textLabel.text=[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i];

}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your rightBarButton selector, you can push (navigate) to the view you want.

You've to `#import "YOurViewControllerName.h"` where the selector defines.

```
-(void) done
{
    YOurViewControllerName * = [[YOurViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOurViewControllerName" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
    [addCreateAlarmVC release]; //if non ARC
}
```

Comment: Where am i supposed to include this? In TableView .m file or in done button's .m file?

Comment: My project is in ARC mode, so what am i supposed to do for [addcreateAlarmVC release];

Comment: @vanya you don't need to `retain` or `release` anything by yourself. ARC automatically manages it.